# Neural correlates of the function of the cardiovascular system?

Tags: human-biology, cardiology, electrophysiology, electrocardiography

Are there any known neural correlates of the function of the cardiovascular system? I'm looking for research results that use standard brain imaging techniques (e.g. electroencephalography, magnetoencephalography, or functional magnetic resonance imaging), and compare the brain signals to respiratory and/or electrocardiographic signals.

Actually, ECG is frequently seen in EEG and MEG recordings. It is considered as an artefact, and typically removed in an early phase. Only the QRS complex is usually visible (or the R wave). If the ECG was recorded from the chest/limbs, proper signals would be gained. It would be interesting to compare the heart rate variability etc. to brain signals but has this for example been already done?

I don't have much background to respiratory signals, so I'm particularly interested about that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Here at Biology.SE we tend to like specific, solid questions. I would recommend you to do a first search on e.g. Google Scholar with the keywords "electrocardyogram electroencephaolgram" or "ECG EEG", or "ECG fMRI" etc etc. Try to pin down your question and specify it. As of now, it is too broad. If the question is put on hold it is likely for this or a related reason. You can always edit it and try to re-open it after that. Some cool questions have gone through this cycle. Interesting question though! Good luck.

Comment: I added some more text to the post.

Comment: Great addition. +1 and I retracted my close vote.